# JSoup does not clean non-ascii string nicely

Tags: java, utf-8, ascii, jsoup

I am using JSoup to clean incoming text from users. Alas, it seems like it does not support non-ascii chars for the cleaning:

assertEquals("привет", Jsoup.clean("привет", Whitelist.none()));

this does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Works fine for me with Jsoup 1.6.3. Are you sure your java file is of correct encoding?

Comment: yes. using 1.6.3 and the java class is utf-8 encoded

Answer (score 1):

What is the default encoding if you run your code? Maybe this one is not UTF-8 but linux / windows default. You can use the VM argument `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to enshure UTF-8.

Checked your code with jsoup 1.6.3 too --> test successful